# Edge-mode operator for semi-infinite SSH chain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, many-body, topological-order

I am asked to show that the SSH-Hamiltonian for a semi-infinite chain with intralattice e interlattice hopping $u$ and $t$, respectively, given by

$\hat{\mathcal{H}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u\hat{c}_{n,A}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{n,B}+t\hat{c}_{n,B}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{n+1,A}+ h.c.$

commutes with the edge-mode operator

$\hat{c}_{L}\propto\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{u}{t})^{n-1}\hat{c}_{n,A}$

in the topological phase, even when moving away from the fully dimerized limit $u=0, t=1$. I basically tried this using only linearity of the commutation and fermionic anticommutation relations but I am probably missing something. Is anyone gone through this calculation before?

Edit:

$[\hat{\mathcal{H}},\hat{c}_{L}]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{u}{t})^{n-1}(u[\hat{c}_{n,A},\hat{c}_{m,A}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,B}+\hat{c}_{m,B}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,A}]\\\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:+t[\hat{c}_{n,A},\hat{c}_{m,B}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m+1,A}+\hat{c}_{m+1,A}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,B}])$

$\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}[\hat{c}_{n,A},\hat{c}_{m,A}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,B}+\hat{c}_{m,B}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,A}] & =\hat{c}_{n,A}\hat{c}_{m,A}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,B}+\hat{c}_{n,A}\hat{c}_{m,B}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,A}-\hat{c}_{m,A}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,B}\hat{c}_{n,A}-\hat{c}_{m,B}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,A}\hat{c}_{n,A} \\
& =\hat{c}_{n,A}\hat{c}_{m,A}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,B}+\hat{c}_{n,A}\hat{c}_{m,B}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,A}+\hat{c}_{m,A}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{n,A}\hat{c}_{m,B}+\hat{c}_{m,B}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{n,A}\hat{c}_{m,A} \\
&=\hat{c}_{n,A}\hat{c}_{m,A}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,B}+\hat{c}_{n,A}\hat{c}_{m,B}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,A}+(\delta_{mn}-\hat{c}_{n,A}\hat{c}_{m,A}^{\dagger})\hat{c}_{m,B} \\ & \:\:\:\:\: -\hat{c}_{n,A}\hat{c}_{m,B}^{\dagger}\hat{c}_{m,A} \\
&=\hat{c}_{n,B}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$
I can't get rid of this remaining annihilation operator and of a similar term arising from the second commutator in the double sum. These can't cancel each other due to the different prefactors, therefore I come to the conclusion that the two commutators in the parentheses have to vanish on their own. Does anyone see something I am blind to at the moment?

Comment: What are you missing? Have you tried the calculation?

Comment: @Alex Yes, I did. But I can't get to $[\hat{\mathcal{H}},\hat{c}_{L}]=0$

Comment: Can you show what you've done, and where exactly you're getting stuck? You have already described how to get the result.

Comment: @Alex I edited my question, look above for my calculation